# What is the purpose of the legacy "legal" and "licensing" tags in EЕ SE?

Tags: support, tag-cleanup

What is the purpose of the legacy [legal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) and [licensing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing) tags in EЕ SE? Should the tags, and questions using these tags be removed as now being off-topic?

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to not nuke these.

Comment: The tag [tag:legal] has got a [tag wiki](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/licensing/info) explaining its usage.  @Matt, these tags aren't being abused.  I don't see a reason for outright nuking 'em.